# WCF & DataContract consumed by .net 2 client

Tags: wcf, service, datacontract

I have developed a WCF service (framework 4.0) which should communicate with a client through BasicHttpBinding.
I have kept my (data)contracts in a separate assembly cause I want them to be reused by multiple clients.
Everything works as expected if I reference my WCF Service as a service (Service References) in a .net 4 client and set "Reuse types in referenced assemblies".
The problem is I have to consume the same WCF service with a .net 2 client. 
In this situation the generated proxy is different from my shared assembly datacontract and I don't seem to be able to reuse it or cast it to the generated proxy.
Is there a way to solve this issue?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, .NET 2.0 has no WCF API at all because it wasn't added until 3.0. So forget sharing the library because there's nothing to really share it with. The .NET 2.0 application will have to use the older WSE (Web Service Extensions) API. [Documentation on WSE is available here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139619.aspx) and you can [download the last version of the WSE API that was made, 3.0 SP3, here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14089).

You should have no problem getting WSE to talk to WCF via a basicHttpBinding. Things would only get complicated if you started using WS-* stuff and, even then, WSE supports a lot of that. It's just hard to find help on it since it's a deprecated API.